# Tutorials for local storage?

Tags: webkit, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am looking for places to learn how to use local storage in chrome extensions.

More specifically:

I want to use options and local storage of variables to run different css content scripts depending on a stored variable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the chrome.* API reference, particularly at the chrome.storage section [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html). They also provide a few examples, [here's one](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#sty).